# Is MapKit being deprecated?

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit, deprecated

Why am I seeing the red strikethrough when I try to import `MapKit` in Xcode 7.3 targeting iOS 9.3 on an iPhone?

[image: red strikethrough]